# aggregate type problem

Tags: sql-server

i have that procedure :

```
Create PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spMerrShenimetBazePerPagese]
    @PunetoriId int
AS
Select p.PunetoriId, p.Emri, p.Mbiemri,p.Vendlindja,pg.Muaji, Sum(p.Paga) as Paga, Sum(pg.Bonusi) as Bonusi, Sum(gj.Vlera) as Gjoba,
(p.Paga+pg.Bonusi-gj.Vlera) as Totali
from Punetoret p 
full outer  join Paga pg on pg.PunetoriId=p.PunetoriId 
full outer  join Gjoba gj on gj.PunetoriId=p.PunetoriId
where p.PunetoriId=@PunetoriId group by p.PunetoriId
```

the exceprion:

*Column 'Punetoret.Emri' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Answer (score 1):

Any column in the SELECT clause that is not part of an aggregate function (SUM, AVG etc) must be listed in the GROUP BY clause.

```
Create PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spMerrShenimetBazePerPagese]
    @PunetoriId int
AS
Select p.PunetoriId, p.Emri, p.Mbiemri,p.Vendlindja,pg.Muaji, Sum(p.Paga) as Paga, 
    Sum(pg.Bonusi) as Bonusi, Sum(gj.Vlera) as Gjoba,
    (p.Paga+pg.Bonusi-gj.Vlera) as Totali
from Punetoret p 
full outer  join Paga pg on pg.PunetoriId=p.PunetoriId 
full outer  join Gjoba gj on gj.PunetoriId=p.PunetoriId
where p.PunetoriId=@PunetoriId 
group by p.PunetoriId, p.Emri, p.Mbiemri, p.Vendlindja, pg.Muaji, p.Paga, pg.Bonusi, gj.Vlera
```

Comment: Thnx for answer,  and how cane fix thatt???

Comment: What do you want to fix?  You can the extra columns to the group by for one thing.  Or remove them from the select list.